# Ubuntu 16.04 Calendar

Tags: 16.04, calendar

Ubuntu 16.04 has a new nice Calendar. It is simple and really useful. I was wondering if this can be installed on Ubuntu 14.04 or on other Linux distributions. What is its name?

Comment: Yes, the package name is `gnome-calendar`, it should be available on Ubuntu 14.04 as well as in other distros.

Comment: @JonasCz It is unable to find that package...

Comment: @JonasCz It is not available as a package for 14.04. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-calendar&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all